# Why isnt my ObservableCollection updating my UI?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm pretty sure I've missed something super tiny but I cant for the life of me figure out where I went wrong.

I'm trying to bind my datagrid to the ConsoleLines property which is infact getting input to it, I debugged it and the ConsoleLines contains multiple strings.
But for some reason its not updating the UI and adding the lines to the gridview.. Or well technically the TextBlock.

So I have my MainWindows setup like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Server Server = new Server();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MasterViewModel();
        }

        private void BtnStart_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Server.StartServer();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am setting the DataContext to a new instance of the MasterViewModel which looks like this

```
public class MasterViewModel
    {
        public Server Server { get; }
            = new Server();
    }
```

And here is my Server class

```
public class Server : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Process pServer;
        public Server()
        {

        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleLines { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public void StartServer()
        {
            pServer = new Process();

            pServer.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
            pServer.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar " + "-Xms512M -Xmx1G spigot.jar";
            pServer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pServer.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            pServer.OutputDataReceived += OKDataReceived;
            pServer.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;

            pServer.Start();

            pServer.BeginErrorReadLine();
            pServer.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        private void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ConsoleLines.Add($"ERROR: {e.Data}"));

        private void OKDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
            => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ConsoleLines.Add($"MESSAGE: {e.Data}"));

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

As far as I know everything is setup correctly I can't see anything that is wrong.

And here is my XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Server.ConsoleLines}" Width="400" Margin="182,109,210,68">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="BtnStart" Click="BtnStart_OnClick" Content="Start Server" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,388,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

EDIT
Initializing a new instance of the server and then using the Button to start the method on a new instance seem to be the issue.. I dont know why though.

Comment: You should use OnPropertyChanged on     ConsoleLines's set

Comment: You bind to the wrong Server instance. There is one in the VM and another in the View and you start the one in the View but the UI is bound to the one in the VM

Comment: @SirRufo The issue was when I created a new server instance and tried starting it with my button, it ran but it didnt bind there

Comment: Ehm, when you have 2 cars (blue and red) and you start the red one did the blue one start too? When you need the blue one running, then start the blue one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `Server` field from your MainWindow and start the Server that is inside your DataContext.

```
private void BtnStart_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MasterViewModel)DataContext).Server.StartServer();
}
```

Alternatively, initialize the view model like this:

```
DataContext = new MasterViewModel { Server = Server };
```

which assigns the Server field value to the Server property in your view model (which must then be read/write). Otherwise you've got two Server instances.